# How to choose content-type in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file, post, undefined

When use post in AngularJS the content-type always confused me.
Content-type:

1. urlencoded
2. undefined
3. ...

   ```
   $http({
       headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
       processData: false,
       method: 'POST',
       cache: false,
       url: sendUrl,
       data: sendObj,
       transformRequest: function (data, headersGetterFunction) {
           return data; // do nothing! FormData is very good!
       }
   })
   ```

I post JSON data with file object.

I found out the content-type must set to undefined. Here is [some clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068849/angular-post-json-with-file-object). But I dont know why must set to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type to `undefined` so that the browser generates one itself. File uploads require multipart requests and those require boundaries between the parts. Thus a generated `Content-Type` header looks like this:

```
Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------99614912995
```

Note the `boundary=`. The value is generated by the browser and you cannot set it yourself.

The reason why you need to set `transformRequest` is that otherwise Angular would send your data as JSON, because that's the default transformation. But you can have it shorter:

```
transformRequest: angular.identity,
```